# Как скрыть пуск C#

Tags: c#

В общем есть малоэкранное приложение на C#(написанное мною), которое накладывается поверх полноэкранного(чужое), при переходе на малоэкранное выскакивает пуск, переключаясь на полноэкранное исчезает. Как избавиться от подобного? Чтобы пуск сидел молча

Comment: Тут скорее всего надо смотреть в сторону WinAPI

Comment: Вот эту посмотрите https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25572/Hiding-the-Taskbar-and-Startmenu-start-orb-in-Wind